# How to collapse my cell properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

while i click the first cell its working properly and hiding correctly.

[image]

while i click second cell,The backend cell has been merged and displaying improperly.
[image]

whats wrong in this code please find out what is wrong in this code.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{

    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return  2;
}
#pragma mark table cell creating and loading the data
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *returncell;
    AntzclubCell *cell;
    WaterPurifierCell *cell1;
   if(indexPath.row==0)
   {
       cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Antz"];
       cell.img_antzClub.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];
       cell.lbl_antzClub.text=@"CAR";
       cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
       cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
       return  cell;

   }
    else if (indexPath.row==1)
    {

   cell1=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"WaterPurifier"];
    cell1.img_waterPurifier.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"water_purifier.png"];
    cell1.lbl_waterPurifier.text=@"WATERPURIFIER";
        return cell1;
    }
    return returncell;
}
#pragma mark expanding height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            if(indexPath.row==selectindex)
        {
            return 350;
        }

        else
        {
            return 132;
        }

            break;
            case 1:
            if(indexPath.row==selectindex)
            {
                return 333;
            }
            else{
                return 132;
            }
        default:
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

   #pragma mark user selecting option
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%d %d",selectindex,indexPath.row);
    if (indexPath.row==selectindex) {
         NSLog(@"%d",selectindex);
        selectindex=-1;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }
        if(selectindex !=-1)
        {
            NSIndexPath *prepath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectindex inSection:0];
            selectindex=indexPath.row;
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:prepath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            return;
        }
        selectindex=indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to hide portions of the cell's content by shrinking its height, you'll need to check that the cell is set up to clip to its bounds (by default this is set to NO).

[image]

Select your prototype cell in the storyboard, and tick the "Clip Subviews" checkbox - the cell should then clip its contents when you shrink the height.